# Toggle specific div and change img jquery

Tags: html, toggle, switch-statement, image, selected

I have a problem with toggle on this list:

```
<div id="list">

    <div id="segment">      // <--- when clicked, toggle segm_content and opener
          <div id="opener">
              <img src="images/open.png" />   // changes when toggled
          </div>
          <div id="segm_content">
              // content to hide/show
          </div>
    </div>

    <div id="segment">      // <--- when clicked, toggle segm_content and opener
          <div id="opener">
              <img src="images/open.png" />   // changes when toggled
          </div>
          <div id="segm_content">
              // content to hide/show
          </div>
    </div>

    ... //and so on

</div>
```

I want clicked *"#segment"* to toggle child *"#segm_content"* and change img in *"#opener"*.

I made it working with this code:

```
$('#segment').toggle(function() {
    $('#opener').html('<img src="images/open.png"/>');
    $('#segm_content').hide(500);
}, function() {
    $('#opener').html('<img src="images/close.png"/>');
    $('#segm_content').show(500);
});
```

But I can't figure out how to do it only for one *"#segment"* at a time.
This code toggles everything, which I don't want.

I am stuck at this point, any suggestions please?
Many thanks!

Comment: I think it's because you have multiple `<div />` elements with the same `id`. jQuery will select all items that match the given selector, even if the selector is an `id` (I think).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried to change `<div>` id's to `#name_number` but is there a way I could set the variables in html and then pass it into this script? Like `onclick="toggle_me('#segment', '#opener', '#segm_content');"`. I cant figure out how to process this data successfully in jquery script :(

Answer (score 0):

I really wouldn't recommend this. The point of an `id` is to reference a unique element. If you want to select multiple elements, you should define a `class` instead and have jQuery call that. Multiple `id`s is invalid HTML. But you *could*, per sé, do this by using changing your jQuery code to the following.

(Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KzVmK/)

```
$('[id="segment"]').toggle(
 function(){
  $(this).find('[id="opener"]').html('<img src="open.png" alt="Close" />');
  $(this).find('[id="segm_content"]').hide(500);
 },
 function(){
  $(this).find('[id="opener"]').html('<img src="close.png" alt="Open" />');
  $(this).find('[id="segm_content"]').show(500);
 }
);​
```

Again, let me stress again that this is a bad idea, because you will not have unique `id` selectors in your document. This is really bad practice. There are times when you will want to select an individual element in the DOM and this will make that next to impossible. I would highly advise you to define a `class` for the elements (you can still define CSS `class`es, e.g. `<div class="opener my-class" />` or `<div class="segm_content my-class" />`).

(Also, a helpful tip with this code: rather than populating the HTML elements with the same image that is also in the jQuery code [which is redundant], leave the `<div id="opener" />` elements empty. Then, right after you define the `toggle` function, run the `click` event, like so: `$('[id="$segment"]').toggle(...).click();`
http://jsfiddle.net/XPXBv/).

Answer (score 0):

General Theme Settings
                
                    
                        
                            Back-Ground Color
                            
                        
                        
                            Text Color

```
          <div class="Settings" id="GTSettings">
            <h3 class="SettingsTitle"><a class="toggle" ><img src="${appThemePath}/images/toggle-collapse-light.gif" alt="" /></a>Content Theme Settings</h3>
            <div class="options">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h4>Back-Ground Color</h4></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="body-backGroundColor" class="themeselector" readonly="readonly"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h4>Text Color</h4></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="body-fontColor" class="themeselector" readonly="readonly"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

$(document).ready(function(){

```
 $(".options").hide();
```

$(".SettingsTitle").click(function(e) {
                    var appThemePath = $("#appThemePath").text();

```
                var closeMenuImg = appThemePath+'/images/toggle-collapse-light.gif';
                var openMenuImg = appThemePath+'/images/toggle-collapse-dark.gif';

                var elem = $(this).next('.options');
                $('.options').not(elem).hide('fast');
                $('.SettingsTitle').not($(this)).parent().children("h3").children("a.toggle").children("img").attr('src', closeMenuImg);
                elem.toggle('fast');
                var targetImg  =  $(this).parent().children("h3").children("a.toggle").children("img").attr('src') === closeMenuImg ?  openMenuImg :  closeMenuImg;
                $(this).parent().children("h3").children("a.toggle").children("img").attr('src', targetImg);


            });
```

});